# Change The Contents Of A Cell Depending On What Is Already In That Cell

Tags: excel, vba

does anyone know how to change the contents of a cell in a spreadsheet depending on what is found in the same cell and then change the colour scheme using VBA

For example

> Cell Value = N/A#
>
> New Cell Value Will Be = Not On Previous Report
>
> Colour Scheme = Black & Bold Text on a yellow background

Or

> Cell Value = Zero or the cell has nothing in so is blank
>
> New Cell Value Will Be = No Update Provided On Previous Report
>
> Colour Scheme = White & Bold Text on a red background

There are also other cell values and these are to be left intact.

Thanks in advance for any help provided it is most appreciated

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/780048-how-do-you-change-contents-cell-depending-what-already-cell.html

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells and run this:

```
Sub repair()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        If r.Text = "#N/A" Then
            r.Value = "Not On Previous Report"
            r.Interior.ColorIndex = 27
            r.Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        End If
        If r.Value = "" Or r.Value = 0 Then
            r.Value = "No Update Provided On Previous Report"
            r.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            r.Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
            r.Font.ColorIndex = 2
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: For reference, the excel formula `IFERROR` could be used if the color change was not part of the requirement.